# Android support design floating action button elevation not visible for colors other than white

Tags: android, android-support-design, floating-action-button

I'm using `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'` and `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` to create a FAB.

When the background tint color is white the elevation (shadow) is very visible.

[image]

But for other colors the elevation not visible.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/create_floating_button"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccentLight"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Beside this problem, even with white color, the button doesn't seem like the ones in [google material design spec](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button).

Check this for example (the shadow's direction is down):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a specific layout-v21 file where you replace `app:elevation` with `android:elevation`. After API 21 you need to do this to maintain a good compatibility.